# Как при помощи JS удалить последний символ из слова в html документе?

Tags: javascript

Допустим слово **Домик**, последняя буква **К** должна удалиться в html документе, то есть в html должно остаться только **"Доми"** ну или хотя бы, чтобы на экране было **"Доми"**

Желательно использовать метод replace.

Набросал код, но я не понимаю, что еще написать, дабы достичь результата.

```js
let word = document.querySelector('.Slovo');
alert(word.innerHTML.replace(/.$/, '')); // по идее /.$/ должна удалить последний символ, но она не удаляет.
// Что еще написать, дабы получить желаемый результат?
```

```html
<article>
 
<p class ="Slovo">  ДОМИК </p> <!-- Надо, чтобы на экране(html) было ДОМИ, вместо Домик  -->
 
</article>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашем случае мешают пробелы после слова. Если от них избавиться, то `replace` отработает как надо.

---

Мой вариант с `slice`

```js
let word = document.querySelector('.Slovo');
 
alert(word.textContent.trim().slice(0, -1));
```

```html
<article>
 
<p class ="Slovo">  ДОМИК </p> <!-- Надо, чтобы на экране было ДОМИ, вместо Домик  -->
 
</article>
```

- **[trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** - для очистки пробелов
- **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** - для взятия всей строки без последнего символа

Comment: А на экране(html) выводится Домик, а мне надо "Доми"

Comment: alert я просто использовал, чтобы показать, что /.$/ не работает

Comment: @Зеленыйчел ну вставь текст обратно в html  через `word.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: А зачем trim? Пробелы не дают работать методу replace? И чем slice лучше replace в моём случае?

Comment: @Зеленыйчел  trim просто обрезать пробелы не более того... не вижу смысла в них вообще. визуально они не видны, а в коде просто лишняя инфа....... slice ничем не лучше, просто проще для манипуляций на мой взгляд. а почему обязательно использовать replace?

Comment: @Зеленыйчел а в целом да, пробелы в вашем случае мешают работе replace. потому что обрезается именно он. если уберёте в конце пробелы, то replace отработает как нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно вместо word.innerHTML = 'ДОМИ' сделать, чтобы именно удалялась последняя буква через replace. Я пробовал, но у меня не получилось. Вот мой неправильный синтаксис word.innerHTML = replace(/.$/, '')

Comment: Нет, так нельзя, т.к. тут нет работы по ссылке

Comment: А что за работа по ссылке?